# what point must be considered before using laravel eloquent relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, relationship

i am working in laravel and i have used its method what i am keen to know that when we use eloquent relationships like

```
1.hasMany
2.belongsTo
3.hasOne
4.belongsToMany
```

so when i want to retrieve data from both tables how do we use laravel methods to get data as per our need

i have done these methods as follows

```
    TABLE::select([
        'field1','field2',
    ])->with('RELATION_NAME')
    ->get();
```

but i failed to get the data from another table so i want to know what are the tips and what should be kept in mind using the eloquent as i have not used it before so it will a great help

Comment: have you read the laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)?? the doc is quite good imo.

Comment: ohh that's a really great help i didn't knew that there is a documentation for that